# How to prove that this function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was working on proving that $S^1$\{(1,0)} with the induced topology by $R^2$ ( product topology) is homeomorphic to the interval ]0,2π[..the homeomorphism is the function f(x)=(Cos(x),Sin(x)).. I already proved the bijection but I'm stuck proving the continuity .. Knowing that a function is continuous if the inverse image of every open set is open.
Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f$ is a homeomorphism, we can use the following. If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Then as @blamethelag suggested, you can prove continuity of $f$ by using results of product functions. (Here, I'll write $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$.)

Let $U\times V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then for every $x\in f^{-1}(U\times V)$, we have that $x\in f_1^{-1}(U)\cap f_2^{-1}(V)\subseteq f^{-1}(U\times V)$. Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous, $f_1^{-1}(U)\cap f_2^{-1}(V)$ is open in the domain of $f$, and this shows $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I would like to use the second argument..  So I need to show that Cos(x) and Sin(x) are continuous functions..  But I'm not sure about the image space.. I mean f is from ]0,2π[ to $S^1$\{(1,0)} , So is it correct to consider Cos(x) and Sin(x) from ]0,2π[ to R and deduce that f is continuous?

Comment: Ahh, I should be more careful about the image space, but you can take $U\times V$ to be $U\cap S^1\setminus\{(1,0)\} ~\times~ V\cap S^1\setminus\{(1,0)\}$, and the argument is the same.

For the second part of your comment: Yes, in this setting it is reasonable to take cos and sin as $[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and to assume they are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The product topology is the smallest topology such that any function at values in the product is continuous if and only if all its coordinates are continuous. Here you only need to check that sin and cosine are continuous.

Comment: Well the theorem says that a function f=(f1,f2) from a topological space  (X, T)  to the product space (X^2,T^2) is continuous if the two functions f1 and f2 from (X, T)  to (X, T)  are continuous..  But in this case here f is from ]0,2π[ to S^1\{(1,0)} .. So we should let the Cos(x) and Sin(x) start from ]0,2π[ to where?

Comment: @AbdellatifOuhaddou My theorem is that for all topological space $(Y, \Theta)$, a function $f : (Y, \Theta) \rightarrow (\prod X , \Theta_{\prod})$ is continuous if and only if the canonical projections are.

Answer (score 1):

Cosine and sine are continuous, hence $f$ is continuous.

To show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, it suffices to show that for each $(x,y)\in C:=S^1\setminus\{(1,0)\}$, there is a neighbourhood of $z$ where $f^{-1}$ is continuous:

- In the upper half plane, $f^{-1}$ is given by $(x,y)\mapsto \frac\pi2-\arctan\frac xy$
- In the lower half plane, $f^{-1}$ is given by $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{3\pi}2+\arctan\frac xy$
- In the left half plane,  $f^{-1}$ is given by $(x,y)\mapsto \pi+\arctan\frac yx$

Comment: I guess you could use calculus to check if it exists. Shouldn’t  f$^{-1}$ be arccos(x)?